# Jstl removing appended symbol

Tags: java, list, jstl, jsp-tags

I have to display a list from the database column titled "Region" .....for every item in that list, if, it contains a child value(Division), it must show something like this,

1  NorthEast       Division1 | Division2

2  Midwest         Division1 | Division2 | Division3

3  South           Division1
....etc

this is what I've done so far, I've put both Regions and Divisions in separate lists and called by looping it inside the `<c:foreach>` as shown below,

```
<c:forEach var="DivisionList" items="${RegionSection.DivisionList}" varStatus="vs">
<c:if test="${DivisionList.divisionID== id}" >  
${DivisionList.title}
</c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

By using the above, I was able to to get and arrange the whole data without the pipe "|"....to append pipe I've tried using the "Last" condition, `<c:if test="${!vs.last}"> | </c:if>` but this only removes the pipe in the last item of the Division list which is not what I intended.....

Is there a workaround for this that could be implemented using Jstl or do I have to use Javascript to get it working? Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should care about the naming of your variables, because the `DivisionList` attribute is actually a `Division`, and should be named as a variable, with a lower-case d: `division`.

Just use the reverse tactic: prepend a pipe before every division except the first one, and use a flag to know if the first one has already been displayed:

```
<c:set var="first" value="true"/>
<c:forEach var="division" items="${RegionSection.DivisionList}">
    <c:if test="${division.divisionID == id}">
        <c:if test="${!first}"> | </c:if><c:out value="${division.title}"/>
        <c:set var="first" value="false"/>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Also, Using `c:out` makes sure that special HTML characters (like `<`, `>`) are properly escaped.

Comment: damn, "First" condition completely skipped my mind........works like a charm....thank you